# Cannot get spring-data-neo4j to connect to remote database

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am building a small proof of concept Spring Boot app which is supposed to connect to a Neo4j instance and perform some basic operations on a couple of different Nodes. If I have the main application class wired to create an embedded Neo4j service using the following code, everything works fine. (this is based on the working example https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-neo4j-data-rest/)

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
    return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("target/hello.db");
}
```

This is the only code sample I can find though for connecting to a Neo4j server from spring boot. If I try connecting to a remote server, the code fails to start with the exception at the end of this question. Our plan is to run a centralized Neo4j instance which is obviously a common production requirement.

How can or should I configure my bean to connect to a remote Neo4j database or is anyone aware of a solid working example of this kind of setup?

Thanks!

My pom.xml includes the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have seen several references to using SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase so I have this being handled in my Main application class is as follows:

```
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableNeo4jRepositories
public class ProfileServiceApplication extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public ProfileServiceApplication() {
        setBasePackage("profile");
    }

    @Bean
    public GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/","neo4j","password");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProfileServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

When I try to run with this configuration, I get the following error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'profileServiceApplication' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'graphDatabaseService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/neo4j/core/UpdateableState
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
```

Comment: Do you have the full project to test it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please share your application as github-project for testing. Perhaps it is also a dependency issue of the spring-boot-starter?  Which boot version are you using??

Perhaps you can check `mvn dependency:tree` if there is any older version of SDN pulled in and if so, update the neo4-version-property for the spring-boot-starter.

Example application is here:

http://neo4j.com/developer/java/#_using_spring_data_neo4j

and it is also in the docs as you correctly saw:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#using_spring_data_neo4j_as_a_neo4j_server_client

Comment: @Michael, Actually I have the dependencies like the ones in the example project, but I get an ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.UpdateableState. And the usage of SpringRestGraphDatabase is deprecated. I use SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase instead.

Comment: It looks like the UpdateableState class is missing in the version 3.3.0 of spring-data-neo4j-rest.

Answer (score 0):

The reference which you are giving doesn't contain Neo4j URL.

Hence Here is **Application.properties** file to connect to your Neo4j.

```
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=Your_Password
```

Start your Neo4j Database as a console application which will run on localhost:7474 port most probably.

command to start:

```
neo4j console
```

Also check the dependency. As the latest version work with only

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```